# C++ prototype initialiser lists?

Tags: c++, class, reference

If I have the following code (simplified version of the problem):

```
class TestA
{
    public:
    int A,B,C;

    TestA(){A = 1; B = 5; C = 10;}
};

//This is a referencing class to allow for universal and consistent operations
class TestB
{
   public:
   int &A, &B, &C; //Note references

   TestB(TestA &A) : A(A.A), B(A.B), C(A.C){}; //This is fine
   TestB(TestC &C) : A(C.A), B(C.B), C(C.C){}; //This needs to be prototyped
};

//Similar class to TestA but in the main program would have...
//...many different and conflicting variables and has to be treated as stand alone
class TestC
{
    public:
    int A, B, C;
    int Size;

    void Function()
    {
        TestB B(*this); //This uses TestB. TestB cannot be prototyped. 
        //etc etc
    }
};
```

I want to know, is it possible to prototype initialiser list based constructors?

If not, what is the alternative? Bear in mind references have to be immediately initialised.

Comment: What do you really mean by "prototyped"? Are you referring to the fact that you need a separate declaration and definition, so that `TestC` is available?

Comment: What do you mean "prototype" initializer lists in ctors?

Comment: TestC passes a copy of itself to TestB so TestB can reference back to TestC. One would then have a TestA copy itself to another TestB allowing the two classes (TestA and TestC) to operate on each other and be passed to TestB expecting functions without needing downcasting or upcasting (which might involve slicing and therefore problems).

Comment: @SSight, can you not just do `TestB(const TestC& t)` to pass your classes to each other?

Comment: TestB is expected to modify the calling class. This is just a very very simple version of the problem. Basically, there are template classes and subderivatives in the original, and I don't want to risk slicing, so TestB is basically a universal adaptor class.

Comment: Sounds like a design smell to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "prototyping" you mean separation of function declaration and definition, this should work:

```
class TestB {
   // ...
   TestB(TestC &C);
};

TestB::TestB(TestC &C) : A(C.A), B(C.B), C(C.C) {
};
```

Comment: @Branko: You forgot the forward declaration, though.

Comment: @Tomalak It's okay. So did I. But I'm aware it'd need to be forward declared. I just didn't know (how) to prototype the initialiser list. I realised there'd be a conflict once the contructor started accessing variables it couldn't possibly know about.

Comment: @SSight3: Your first step is to stop using this non-sensical phrase "prototype the initialiser list". It's a "_member_ initialiser" and you don't "prototype" it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separately declare and define a constructor with a member initialiser list:

```
struct B;              // <-- (forward declaration of B)
struct A {
   A(B& b);            // <-- A ctor declaration
   B& b;
};

struct B {             // <-- (real definition of B)
   A a;
};

A::A(B& b) : b(b) {};  // <-- A ctor definition (with member-initialiser!)
```

The member initialiser list goes with the definition, not the declaration.

Comment: I think by prototyping he means the declaration of the used object in the initializer list.

Comment: @pmr: Yes, which he can now do because the _use_ of it has been moved to some other place later in his code.

Comment: @SSight3: You're very welcome. These circular dependencies can be made to work with forward declarations, but they are also a bit of a design smell and should, in most cases, be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Original question is already answered, but I couldn't help comment on the design.

These 3 classes are totally in love with each other.. :).. I mean the unwanted circular dependencies and tight coupling and so on..

Why not have TestC and TestA extend TestB?

Assuming you have very good reasons for not doing that, other option is this:

**Read comments in code**

```
class TestX
{
public:
    int A,B,C;

    TestX()
    {
        A = 1;
        B = 5;
        C = 10;
    }
};

// "int A,B,C;" coming from baseclass now.
class TestA : public TestX {};

// fwd decl not needed anymore.
// class TestC;

class TestB
{
public:
    int &A, &B, &C; //Note references

    // dealing with TestX instead.
    TestB(TestX &X) : A(X.A), B(X.B), C(X.C) {};
};

class TestC : public TestX
{
public:
    // coming from baseclass now
    // int A,B,C;
    int Size;

    void Function()
    {
        // moved out to some other place.. main() in this case.
        // TestB B(*this);
    }
};

// not needed anymore..
// TestB::TestB(TestC &C): A(C.A), B(C.B), C(C.C) {}

int main ()
{
    TestC c;
    TestA a;

    TestB bc(c);
    TestB ba(a);

    // your primary usecase (referencing class to allow for universal and consistent operations)
    // is satisfied, without changing anything in the client code.
    // You can still use c as TestC where "int Size" or "Function" are needed.

    return 0;
}
```

Now the dependencies are:

```
X <---- A
^   |__ C
|
B
```

Comment: It's a clever idea, and if I do redesign I'd likely try to incorporate this, but there are a lot of header files I've written, and the prototyping/design is pretty bad (my own fault). Once I've done basic construction (working classes etc) I'd hope to submit it for design and improvement criticisms.

Comment: Sure.. remember you'll always find "good reason(s)" for not doing the right thing immediately. :)